# JavaScript not working with RadTextBox

Tags: javascript, telerik, asp.net-ajax, rad-controls

```
 <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function ValidatePhoneNumbers() {

                var phone = document.getElementById('txtPhone1');
                var mobile =document.getElementById('txtPhone2');
                alert(phone.value);
                if ((phone.value == null || phone.value == "") && (mobile.value == null || mobile.value == "")) {
                    alert('something');
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    alert('something');
                    return true;
                }
           }

        </script>
```

```
<tr>
                                        <td>
                                         <label for="txtPhone1">
                                                Phone :</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtPhone1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone_One") %>' Type="Number" Skin="Windows7" CssClass="txt">
                                                     <numberformat allowrounding="false" keepnotroundedvalue="False" GroupSeparator=""></numberformat>
                                            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="rqfldPhone1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPhone1"
                                                Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" ValidationGroup="Submit" ToolTip="Enter Phone Number"  ></asp:CustomValidator>
                                        </td>
```

```
 <telerik:RadButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "Insert" : "Update" %>'
                                    CommandName='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "PerformInsert" : "Update" %>'
                                    Skin="Windows7" ValidationGroup="Submit">
```

When i add "OnClientClicked" to RadButton to call javaScript ( "return ValidatePhoneNumbers" )  in javaScript It showing NULL WHY ?
there are 2 rad textbox txtphone1 and txtphone2 ,
Actually i want to validate these textbox , if any one is filled no prob otherwise i need to show A error/warning msg.
pls help me

> Actually  ".value" is not shownig in javascript (document.GetelementById.value)

Comment: Try with ClientID like this:  document.getElementById('<%= txtPhone1.ClientID %>').value

Comment: but its showing error that txtPhone1 is not in the currrent context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with telerik controls the javascript to find controls and do operations is different that of we work with normal html and javascript:

To find radcombox:

```
$find("<%=RadComboBox1.ClientID %>");//for example
```

Let work with your problem:

```
var phone=$find("<%=txtPhone1.ClientID %>");
var mobile=$find("<%=txtPhone2.ClientID %>");
alert(phone.get_value());//use get_value() to get the value of radcombobox
if ((phone.get_value() == null || phone.get_value() == "") && (mobile.get_value() == null ||  mobile.get_value()== "")) {
        alert('something');
        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    }
    else {
        alert('something');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The OnClientClicked event will run a function by name with 2 parameters, these are akin to that used by .NET event handlers (sender and eventArgs). The Telerik controls don't cancel the action in the same manner as general HTML objects in that `return false;` doesn't cancel a post back. Instead, the Telerik API provides a set_cancel() function in the eventArgs parameter.

```
function ValidatePhoneNumbers(sender, eventArgs) {
    var phone = document.getElementById('<%= txtPhone1.ClientId %>'); // Corrected as per my comment
    var mobile =document.getElementById('<%= txtPhone2.ClientId %>'); // Corrected as per my comment
    alert(phone.value);
    if ((phone.value == null || phone.value == "") && (mobile.value == null || mobile.value == "")) {
        alert('something');
        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
    }
    else {
        alert('something');
    }
}
```

You don't need to set the `OnClientClicked="return ValidatePhoneNumbers"` instead I would recomment using `OnClientClicking ="ValidatePhoneNumbers"` (see: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-onclientclicking.html)

For more information regarding client side event handlers, see: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/programming/clientevents/defaultcs.aspx

The validator should trigger when the button is pressed, if it is not set `CausesValidation="True"` and maybe consider a RequiredFieldValidator to ensure it is populated before postback.

Comment: I should also add that the document.getElementById won't work correctly as the element will have a different ID given to it to ensure "uniqueness". Supplement the "txtPhone1"/"txtPhone2" with the txtPhone1.ClientID (taken from the code behind) and it should be able to find the control. $find(<%= txtPhoneId.ClientId %>) will get the Telerik object and allow you to use the Telerik API such as get_value() to get the current value